# Position of tollbar is not set on the top and it is hiding behind other content

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-toolbar

I have tool bar and I want to show two menu icons i.e myicon_clearnotifications and /myicon_goback but when I click only notifications are showing not these two menu items on toolbar. It looks that my toolbar is hinding behind the notifications (i want notifications to show below my toolbar) other content is showing but toolbar is not.

XML toolbar code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context="Activities.AllNotifications">
    
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/allNotifications_tollbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#5A6E64"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

        />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/allNotifications_RecyclerView"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

My menu items code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/allNotifications_item_clear"
        android:title="CLEAR"
        android:icon="@drawable/myicon_clearnotifications"
        android:checkable="true"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/allNotifications_item_goBack"
        android:title="GO BACK"
        android:icon="@drawable/myicon_goback"
        android:checkable="true"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
</menu>
```

and this is my java code

```
package Activities;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;


import com.example.connectsocialmediaapp.R;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.WriteBatch;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import AdapterClasses.AllNotificationsAdapter;
import ModelClasses.Model_AllNotifications;

public class AllNotifications extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseFirestore objectFirebaseFirestore;
    private RecyclerView objectRecyclerView;

    private AllNotificationsAdapter objectAllNotificationsAdapter;
    private Toolbar objectToolbar;

    private FirebaseAuth objectFirebaseAuth;
    private Dialog objectDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_notifications);

        objectFirebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        objectFirebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        attachJavaToXML();
        getAllNotificationIntoRV();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        objectAllNotificationsAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        objectAllNotificationsAdapter.stopListening();
    }

    private void getAllNotificationIntoRV()
    {
        try
        {
            if(objectFirebaseAuth!=null) {
                String currentLoggedInUser = objectFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
                Query objectQuery = objectFirebaseFirestore.collection("userProfileData")
                        .document(currentLoggedInUser).collection("Notifications");

                FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Model_AllNotifications> objectOptions =
                        new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model_AllNotifications>()
                                .setQuery(objectQuery, Model_AllNotifications.class).build();
                objectAllNotificationsAdapter = new AllNotificationsAdapter(objectOptions);
                objectRecyclerView.setAdapter(objectAllNotificationsAdapter);

                objectRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_user_online, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    ArrayList<String> objectStringArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    private void clearAllNotifications()
    {
        try
        {
            if(objectFirebaseAuth!=null)
            {
                final String currentLoggedInUser=objectFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
                objectFirebaseFirestore.collection("userProfileData")
                        .document(currentLoggedInUser)
                        .collection("Notifications")
                        .get()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful())
                                {
                                    for(QueryDocumentSnapshot objectQueryDocumentSnapshot:task.getResult())
                                    {
                                        objectStringArrayList.add(objectQueryDocumentSnapshot.getId());
                                        WriteBatch objectWriteBatch=objectFirebaseFirestore.batch();

                                        for(int count=0;count<objectStringArrayList.size();count++)
                                        {
                                            objectWriteBatch.delete(
                                                    objectFirebaseFirestore.collection("userProfileData")
                                                    .document(currentLoggedInUser)
                                                    .collection("Notifications")
                                                    .document(objectStringArrayList.get(count))
                                            );
                                        }
                                        objectWriteBatch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if(task.isSuccessful())
                                                {
                                                    Toast.makeText(AllNotifications.this, "Notifications Cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                                else if(!task.isSuccessful())
                                                {
                                                    Toast.makeText(AllNotifications.this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_user_online, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void attachJavaToXML()
    {
        try
        {
            objectDialog =new Dialog(this);
            objectDialog.setContentView(R.layout.please_wait_dialog);

            objectToolbar=findViewById(R.id.allNotifications_tollbar);
            setSupportActionBar(objectToolbar);
            objectRecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.allNotifications_RecyclerView);

            objectToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.all_notifications_menu);


            objectToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId())
                    {
                        case R.id.allNotifications_item_clear:
                            clearAllNotifications();
                            return true;
                        case R.id.allNotifications_item_goBack:
                            startActivity(new Intent(AllNotifications.this,MainContentPage.class));
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with replacing toolbar xml code with below code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/allNotifications_tollbar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#5A6E64"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

    />


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/allNotifications_RecyclerView"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options here.

First change the RelativeLayout to Linear layout or add
`android:layout_below ="@+id/allNotifications_tollbar"` to the Recycler view.